# Mascarpone and Almond pasta Sauce?

Tags: sauce, pasta, italian-cuisine, mascarpone

While in Italy I had a pasta sauce that was made with mascarpone and almonds (the almonds were ground fine) it had the look of Alfredo sauce. I cannot recall the name of the sauce. I have searched far and wide for such a recipe. Is anyone familiar with this sauce? If so, would you PLEASE share the name?

Comment: http://www.ricettegustose.it/Primi_sughi_vari_html/Pennette_mandorle_e_mascarpone.html no special name for it AFAIK, just "mascarpone e mandorle" meaning "mascarpone and almond"

Comment: @belisarius Your response should have been posted as an "answer", not a "comment" so that the question could be resolved.

Comment: @Allison In fact, I'm not completely sure about it "not having a name". I prefer to leave the answer to an Italian or someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for "mascarpone e salsa di mandorle"

Here's an example recipe that I found. 
http://www.subitoricette.it/ricetta-spaghetti-mascarpone-mandorle/

Answer (score 0):

No mention of almonds in this recipe, but everything I have tried from this site has been absolutely fantastic. You could likely add finely ground almonds to this and arrive at something similar to what you had in Italy: http://www.italianfoodforever.com/2012/02/pasta-with-mascarpone-chicken-sun-dried-tomatoes-spinach/